# Video Writing on another thread (Python OpenCV)

Tags: python, python-multithreading, opencv

I have some usecase where I am doing video capturing on main loop and doing video recording of captured frames on another thread. When I try to run video after that I get error :
This is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

from threading import Thread
import threading
import time

recordVideo = True
detected = True

def VideoWriting():
    global frame
    global writeVideo
    firstTime = True
    writeVideo = False
    out = cv2.VideoWriter()
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

    while recordVideo:
        if(True == firstTime and True == detected and True == writeVideo):
            print("init")
            out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc , 20.0, (frame.shape[0],frame.shape[1]) )
            firstTime = False
        if(True == writeVideo):
            out.write(frame)
            print("VideoWriting :: Frame")
            writeVideo = False
        if(False == detected):
            firstTime = True
            out.release()
    
    if(out.isOpened() ):
        print("Released")
        out.release()

th = []

th.append(Thread(target=VideoWriting) )
th[-1].daemon = True
th[-1].start()

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        writeVideo = True
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

recordVideo = False

for thd in th:
    thd.join()
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance, for help.

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved your problem.
You've got to change only 2 lines of your code.

Instead of:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
```

use:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
```

And instead of:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc , 20.0, (frame.shape[0],frame.shape[1]) )
```

use:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4))))
```